# Python Lottery generator I'm trying to figure out how to add a number input, and separate them on lines and be x amount of num long

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Lottery Generator
def lotto():
    import random
    integer = []
    for number in range(0,5):
        integer.append(random.randint(1,101))
    return integer

print (lotto())
```

This is what I have so far. Not I try to input a number. I can input a number and multiply it within the method, by using

```
numInput = int(input("How many number sets do you need? "))
```

and adding that to the end

```
print(lotto() * numInput)
```

but then it just gives me a number. What I'm trying to get is something like this

```
[5, 54, 84, 100, 72]
[16, 31, 95, 47, 10]
```

...etc. I want to print the output of `lotto` for `numInput` times.

Comment: This is unclear.  How does `numInput` relate to `lotto()`?

Comment: it was to input a number of times the lotto numbers were to by displayed(for example inputting "5" will give you 5 sets of numbers

Comment: The above set you have printed out, is that for input 2 or 5?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please ensure, that your sentences are clear structured and without any grammar or spelling mistakes (to your best knowledge of cource!). I had a hard time to understand, what you really want. Also don't add fluff like "hahaha", or thank you. They are not needed for a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the amount of times inputted for numInput

```
def lotto():
    import random
    integer = []
    for number in range(0,5):
        integer.append(random.randint(1,101))
    return integer

numInput = int(input("How many number sets do you need? "))

for i in range(0, numInput):
    print (lotto())
```

If you would like to change the number of results returned per set. Then your function can accept an argument. For instance if you wanted 10 results per set.

```
def lotto(numbers):
    import random
    integer = []
    for number in range(0,numbers):
        integer.append(random.randint(1,101))
    return integer

numInput = int(input("How many number sets do you need? "))

for i in range(0, numInput):
    print (lotto(10))
```

Comment: "within the method" otherwise, great response no complaints :)

Answer (score 0):

Have your function take in a variable and then run a loop inside your function that appends that many of your lottery sets to a list and then return that list!

```
import random
def lotto(repetitions):
    lista = []
    for i in range(repetitions):
        integer = []
        for number in range(0,5):
            integer.append(random.randint(1,101))
        lista.append(integer)
    return lista

number = int(input("How many sets: "))
print(lotto(number))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 lotto.py
> How many sets: 3
> [[45, 99, 74, 64, 60], [65, 86, 51, 35, 93], [60, 4, 69, 14, 60]]
> ```